# create a tag "<text>" part of the word is cut. c3.js - d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I'm adding a `<text>`, and would like to introduce this label YABADABADOOOO the word, then I assign a position in x and y to put it where I want. in this image I show the place in which I want to put:

[image]

for some strange reason it text ("YABADABADOOOO")is not fully shown. What can I do?

this is my code:

```
chartData=[
 ['data1',60,10,4,20],
 ['data2',30,30,5,20],
 ['data3',30,30,4,20]
]

var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
size: {
    height: 500,
},
data: {
    columns: chartData,
    colors:{
      data1:'#00af50',
      data2:'#F7931E',
      data3: '#FF0000'
    },
    names:{
      data1:'namedata1',
      data2:'namedata2',
      data3:'namedata3'

    },

    type:'bar',

    labels: {
      //format: function (v, id, i, j) { return "Default Format"; },
      format: {

       data1: function (v, id, i, j) { 
         return "text 30 characters->.........."; 
       },
        data2: function (v, id, i, j) { 

         return "Format for data2"; 
       },
        data3: function (v, id, i, j) { 

         return "other text"; 
       },
      }
    }
},


tooltip: {
    show: false
},    
legend: {
    show: false
},
axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['001', '002','003','004'],
         tick: {

         format: function (d) { 
          return "" ; }
        }
    }        
}    
});

var arrayOfPics = [
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract",
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/animal",
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/business",
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/cats",
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/sports",
"http://lorempixel.com/40/40/food"
];


d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
.each(function(d,i){
// clear tick contents and replace with image
var self = d3.select(this);
//  self.selectAll("*").remove();
self.append('image')
  .attr("xlink:href", arrayOfPics[i])
  .attr("x", -40)
  .attr("y", -20)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
 });

 d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
.each(function(d,i){
// clear tick contents and replace with image
var self = d3.select(this);
//  self.selectAll("*").remove();
  self.append('text')
   .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", -110)
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text("YABADABADOOOOO");

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zdndpd3x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c3.js` is applying a clip-path to the axis.  I don't know much about `c3`'s internals so I'm not sure why they are doing this.  **But** you can remove it:

```
d3.select('.c3-axis-x').attr("clip-path", "");
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdndpd3x/1/).

Comment: @yavg, not trying to be rude, but if you need to develop more advanced functionality in your SVG based charts and graphs, you'll need to study up on the technologies being used.  For instance, there's [lots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) of [documentation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html) on [SVG clippaths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html).

Comment: @Mark there's a lot of discussion on Meta about these questions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319937/a-stream-of-similar-questions-from-two-different-users?cb=1 personally I'd recommend not answering them based on a lack of research etc.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for the heads up.  I caught on to the "duo" after the first 3 questions I answered and then gave up on it.